# fetch wordpress post slug in header meta tag

Tags: php, wordpress

let's say I have 2.. domain A and B

how do you fetch WordPress post URL (only the URL, not the domain part) from domain A so it points to domain B

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://domainB<?php the_permalink(); ?>" hreflang="za" />
```

so the output will be printed something like this

```
<link rel="alternate" href="domainA/postname" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="domainB/postname" hreflang="za" />
```

These code `https://domainB<?php the_permalink(); ?>` gave me error, `nonce_failure`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically change the link on each page. This might help -

```
$domains_1 = 'https://' . domainA . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domains_2 = 'https://' . domainB . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo "<link rel='alternate' href='".$domains_1."' hreflang='en'/>";
echo "<link rel='alternate' href='".$domains_2."' hreflang='za'/>";
```

Comment: goes into `header.php?`

Comment: If you want to add inside header.php, you can add manually to 

```themes > themes-name > header.php```

OR
 
`
add_action("wp_headers", "example_test");

function example_test(){
 $domains_1 = "https://" . domainA . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 $domains_2 = "https://" . domainB . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

 echo "<link rel='alternate' href='".$domains_1."' hreflang='en'/>";
 echo "<link rel='alternate' href='".$domains_2."' hreflang='za'/>";
}
`